# Es posible convertir una variable Double a String dentro de un CanvasText?

Tags: canvas

Para no tener que declarar una variable es posible hacer la conversión de una variable double a un string dentro de un CanvasText ?

```
double cxg = 74.35;
canvas.drawText(cxg, 250, 10, paint);
```

Esto me dá error ya que cxg es double.

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que estás programando en Java, puedes usar la función [`String.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(double)) para convertir de `double` a `String`:

```
double cxg = 74.35;
canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(cxg), 250, 10, paint);
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El metódo [drawText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText(java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) ciertamente necesita un `String` para definir el texto que será mostrado:

```
drawText (String text, 
                float x, 
                float y, 
                Paint paint)
```

en este debes convertir el valor `double` a `String`, puedes realizarlo mediante estas opciones:

---

Concatenando un `String` (vació):

```
canvas.drawText(""+cxg, 250, 10, paint);
```

---

Usando el método [String.valueOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(float)) :

```
canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(cxg), 250, 10, paint);
```

---

Usando el método [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) de la variable con valor tipo `double`:

```
canvas.drawText(cxg.toString(), 250, 10, paint);
```